# key to toggle line comment in python

Tags: python, comment

I'm wondering what is the key to toggle line comment in python, because <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> is not working, although it's the line toggle command mentioned in the docs, despite that it's working with block comments when text is selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: well I could use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and put a <kbd>#</kbd> or remove it but I'd like to find out about comment toggle.

Comment: The word Python ,between parentheses,  is in the bottom of the screen, isn't that it?

Comment: Yes, that is. Do `M-x comment-region` or `M-x uncomment-region` work?

Comment: Yes they both do!

Comment: @Name I just tried pressing M-; on an uncommented line and it added a # after a some blank spaces in the end of the line.

Comment: `M-;` is a shortcut for `M-x comment-dwim`. Do `M-x describe-binding` and make sure that `M-;` is binded to `comment-dwim`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26178/discussion-between-baha-hi-and-name).

Comment: Another suggestion is to use `M-x comment-or-uncomment-region` and bind it to your preferred shortcut.

Comment: Evil-nerd-commenter Read first line of readme at least

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which version of Emacs you're using, but there is (will be) <kbd>C-x C-;</kbd> in Emacs 25, it runs `comment-line` that seem to have the behavior you want.

Comment: I'm currently using Emacs 24.4.1, I'll upgarde and try your suggestion, thanks! P.S: C-x C-; now seems to set comment column to 0.

Comment: Wait, there is NOTHING similar for emacs24 ?!

Answer (score 0):

From [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el)

```el
(defun comment-region-lines (beg end &optional arg)
  "Like `comment-region' (which see), but comment or uncomment whole lines."
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (when (> beg end) (setq beg  (prog1 end (setq end  beg))))
  (let ((bol  (save-excursion (goto-char beg) (line-beginning-position)))
        (eol  (save-excursion (goto-char end) (if (bolp) (point) (line-end-position)))))
    (comment-region bol eol arg)))
```

I bind it to `C-x C-;`.

Answer (score 0):

;; The following code (select-current-line) is due to Xah Lee, see  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-12/msg01183.html

```
(defun select-current-line ()
  "Select the current line"
  (interactive)
 (beginning-of-line) ; move to end of line
  (set-mark (line-end-position)))
```

Now we can define the following function  (which uses the idea from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697222/ due to Gerstmann but it is not identical to that answer).

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region ()
  "comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region"
  (interactive)
(save-excursion (if (region-active-p) (comment-dwim nil)
  (select-current-line) (comment-dwim nil)
  )))
```

Now you can define a shortcut for it:

```
 (eval-after-load "python"
'(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "M-;") #'comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region))
```